# Django display radio button choice

Tags: python, django, forms

i want to display vaule_fields of my User model as selectable choice radiobuttons, any idea how to do this?

```
...
```

template.html

```
....
```

currently they are displayed as input fields?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of gender choices displayed as radio buttons.

```
MODELS.PY ********************************************************
#GENDER CHOICES OPTIONS
    GENDER_COICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
    ('O', 'Other'),
   )

gender = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=GENDER_COICES,
 default="N/A")
*****************************************************************

FORMS.PY ********************************************************
class UserQForm(UserCreationForm):
    """ This is a form used to create a user. """

    # Form representation of an image
    QUserPictureProfile = forms.ImageField(label="Profile Picture",
     allow_empty_file=True, required=False)

    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=255,
     widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Confirmation", max_length=255,
     widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    #GENDER CHOICES OPTIONS
    GENDER_COICES = (
      ('M', 'Male'),
      ('F', 'Female'),
      ('O', 'Other'),
    )

    gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=GENDER_COICES)


    class Meta:

        model = QUser

        fields = ('QUserPictureProfile', 'gender',
        'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'password1',
         'password2','phone_number',)

    def clean(self):
        """ Clean form fields. """

        cleaned_data = super(UserQForm, self).clean()

        password1 = cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match!")
```

---

Comment: I dont know if that help me out or at least not completly of curse it shows how to display radio buttons, thanks for that ;) but do you also have a hint for me how to handle these integerFields: acc_usd_balance', 'acc_eur_balance', 'acc_rub_balance.

In the end a vaule gets transfered from one user account to another one so i also have to keep that in mind on my views.py because if have to subtract from the vaule of the sending account and add it to the receiving user account.

Comment: Well you could render your `Modelform` manually and put link tags `<a>` around the check boxes, each account would have its own view and then each selection made will be a form in which you can change the form `action` to the account in which the user selects on.